# Can I display/create jsTree on button click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree, jquery-events

I have a div `id="result"` that I use to display results of users actions. I put there plain text and html too. After each user action this div is overwritten with new `results`.

Now I want to display inside this div an instance of [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) I have working jsTree that loads nicely on page load but it doesn't load after `<div id="tree"></div>` is inserted inside my result div.

I tried two lines below but none worked.

```
 $("#tree").jstree("loaded");  
 $("#tree").jstree("refresh");
```

Any idea how to make the jsTree to be displayed a **after button click**? Please play on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/fmn6g/7/) where you can see one tree already and I want another to be displayed after clicking the button. I am after the tree not the text.

I think I need to reload or refresh the tree after I place jstree div inside html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tree2 was not created in the first place since `<div id="tree2">` was not there when you call '$("#tree2").jstree'.

So when you press the button, first tree is correctly refreshed but tree2 is not shown for the reason above.

At button pressed, you have to recreate tree2 by calling '$("#tree2").jstree', or you can just hide `<div id="tree2">` when you call `$("#tree2").jstree`. I just updated your fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/fmn6g/10/) so you can try.

Comment: I like the first option better. Made it work here http://jsfiddle.net/radek/fmn6g/11/ Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To make it happen on a Button Click, just do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#button-id').click(function() {
 $("#tree").jstree("loaded");  
 $("#tree").jstree("refresh"); 
});
});
</script>
```

Remember to change `button-id` to the actual `id` of the button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you try in jsfiddle? I believe that I tried that already.

Comment: @Radek Hmm, when I click the button it seems to work already. Is there something that isn't happening that you want to happen?

Comment: I updated jsfiddle, hope it's clearer now. I want the tree to be displayed after clicking the button. Now, second tree.

Comment: Oh, so the second tree is not displaying corrently? I will look into it and see if I can find the problem. By the way, I am curious to know why you are using traditional JS: `document.getElementById("results").innerHTML+="tree #2<div id=\"tree2\"></div>";` in the middle of jQuery? It probably still works right, just I'm wondering why you have to use that instead of jQuery.

Comment: The second tree is not displaying at all :-) Well, I recently started to use jQuery so now and then I use/copy old code. I am very new with both js and jQuery though.

Comment: Oh okay. I hope I can find a fix to this for you. I'm not the best JavaScript person around, but I am fairly good at it.