# How to initialize jsTree using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I make jsTree by this way:

```
$("#myTree").jstree({
                "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "dnd"],
                "themes": {
                    "theme": "default",
                    "dots": false,
                    "icons": false,
                    "url": "../../Content/jsTreeThemes/default/style.css"
                },
                "json_data": {
                   "data" : []
                }
});
```

And user sees page with empty jsTree. I must initialize my jsTree when user make some action. But I musn't use ajax initialization (I musn't use "ajax" in "json_data"). I must initialize my jsTree using only string like this:

```
var stringJSON = [{
    "attr": {
        "id": "1",
        "rel": "root",
        "mdata": null
    },
    "data": "title": "root_jsTree",
    "icon": null
}, "state": "open",
"children": [{
    "attr": {
        "id": "7",
        "rel": "folder",
        "mdata": null
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "1",
        "icon": null
    },
    "state": "",
    "children": [{
        "attr": {
            "id": "10",
            "rel": "folder",
            "mdata": null
        },
        "data": {
            "title": "leaf",
            "icon": null
        },
        "state": "",
        "children": []
    }]
}, {
    "attr": {
        "id": "8",
        "rel": "folder",
        "mdata": null
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "leaf",
        "icon": null
    },
    "state": "",
    "children": [{
        "attr": {
            "id": "9",
            "rel": "folder",
            "mdata": null
        },
        "data": {
            "title": "leaf",
            "icon": null
        },
        "state": "",
        "children": []
    }]
}]
}]'
```

No matter how I receive this string, when user wants see tree I've already had this string. 
And here I get question: How can I initialize jsTree and display it for user using only string below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you want something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/radek/fmn6g/11/

- Where I insert jsTree on a button click.
- The javascript on click function inserts 'jstree' div and also contains jsTree definition.
- As you can see I also use json data type.

More info in my question [display jsTree on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117538/can-i-display-create-jstree-on-button-click)

Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution:

```
var jsTreeSettings = $("#myTree").jstree("get_settings");
jsTreeSettings.json_data.data = $.parseJSON(stringJSON);
$.jstree._reference("myTree")._set_settings(jsTreeSettings);

// Refresh whole our tree (-1 means root of tree)
$.jstree._reference("myTree").refresh(-1);
```

This solution will work even if we set up AJAX for loading model before.

From documentation:

> If both data and ajax are set the initial tree is rendered from the data string. 
>   When opening a closed node (that has no loaded children) an AJAX request is made.

More information is here http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data

I decided to use this solution because I must change `stringJSON` several times and rebuild tree using this changed string (without reloading page).